# Change data in Mat object in OpenCV but also affect the data in another Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm writing a OpenCV program in C++, version 2.4.13. I initilized a vector vec containing Mat pointers with zeros. I change the content of vec[0], and find that the data in vec[1] is also affected, which means that not all pixels are zeros now. If I change the data of vec[1], data in vec[0] is also affected. Changing vec[0] will affect the first 3 rows in vec[1], while changin vec[1] will affect the last 3 rows in vec[0]. I think their memory may have overlapped to each other.

This is my code:

```
vector<Mat> result;
int row = responseMaps[0] -> rows;
int col = responseMaps[0] -> cols;
for (int i = 0; i < responseMaps.size(); ++i) {
    Mat classification = Mat(row, col, responseMaps[0] -> depth(), Scalar(0));
    result.push_back(classification);
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
        result[1].at<double>(i, j) = responseMaps[0] -> at<double>(i, j);

        ++count;
    }
}
bool done = false;
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
        if (!isZero(result[0].at<double>(i, j))) {
            cout << result[0].at<double>(i, j) << "\n";
            cout << i << " " << j << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the original Mats double?

Comment: responseMap is CV_16U

Comment: Then, why are you using `at<double>` instead of `at<ushort>`?

Comment: I see the problem, thank you. If I want to assign a pixel value of a CV_8U image to a CV_16U image, what can I do?

Comment: The second `for` loop seems like it could be replaced by [`convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3f356665bb0ca452e7d7723ccac9a810). `count` will simply be `row * col`.